Python member variables of different data types not getting updated in different thread with same priority
Consider this sample code:
class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.bool = False
        self.string = ""
        thread = Thread(target = self.target)
        thread.start()

    def target(self):
        while True:
            if self.bool:
                print("Bool changed")
                break

            if self.string != "":
                print("String changed")
                break
    
    def changeBool(self):
        self.bool = True
    
    def changeString(self):
        self.string = "sample"

var = Test()
var.changeString()
var.changeBool()

Here, I have two member variables in a class: a boolean and a string. In the constructor, I start a new thread to run a function which basically tells me which of the two variables gets modified inside the thread first.
When I run this program, even though I am calling changeString() first, the output is always "Bool changed". This means that the boolean is getting updated inside the thread faster than the string. Why does this happen? And how can I ensure that self.bool gets updated inside the thread immediately after it is modified in the main thread?

Your loop checked for self.bool first before self.string, so if both got updated at the same time in between the end of a loop and the start of the next, that's the one that will be reported first. Try eliminating this possibility by swapping the condition checks, or add an additional check at the beginning for both conditions.

If you need to preserve the order of your "events" i would recommend a queue. There is a thread safe variant in the std lib

Why do you need the polling function in the first place? Just have the change functions report that it has changed.

Put a call to time.sleep() after var.changeString() and you should get the expected output.

@Barmar this is just an example. In my actual code, I am running an infinitely-running process in the separate thread, and bool and string would be two flags which can terminate the process in case they have specific values.

@Barmar regarding making use of time.sleep(), I thought of that too, but it doesn't feel like the 'correct' way of solving this problem. So I wanted to ask for any other approaches. I will try using a queue as Wombatz has said.

I didn't mean it as a solution, just a way to show that it isn't always "Bool changed". Your code is obviously just a toy example, and this is a way to tweak it.

@metatoaster I tried this, and the results were random, as expected. Most times it would be "both changed" but occasionally it would show "bool changed" or "string changed"

Hi @Wombatz a queue did solve my problem. Thanks! If you want to post an answer, I will approve that. In the meantime, I posted an answer myself.

Yeah, I was explaining why/how you got the weird output that you saw, and now that you also explored that other solution you can see that the other thread can change things in an indeterminate manner which will interfere the check, but good to see that you saw what you actually needed which is a thread-safe queue.

I tried implementing a thread-safe queue as per @Wombatz's suggestion, and that worked. Here's the modified code:
class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        thread = Thread(target = self.target)
        thread.start()

    def target(self):
        while True:
            try:
                message = self.queue.get_nowait()
                if message[0] == "bool":
                    print(f"Bool changed to {message[1]}")
                    break

                if message[0] == "string":
                    print(f"String changed to {message[1]}")
                    break
            except queue.Empty: pass
    
    def changeBool(self):
        self.queue.put(("bool", True))
    
    def changeString(self):
        self.queue.put(("string", "hello"))

var = Test()
var.changeBool()
var.changeString()

